# JSF2 MetaRule and MethodBinding

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

Do I still have to care about MethodBinding in a subclass of MetaRule#applyRule?
I would like to fully remove any deprecated APIs from my code and only support JSF2+

I have a MethodRule class that extends MetaRule like seen in some frameworks like Primefaces.
So what do you think, do I have to keep the MethodBinding code or can I just remove it?

Comment: If that code is internal, just remove it and see if the unit tests pass all.

Comment: Does any jsf2+ impl still pass method bindings or only method expressions? The MethodRules would be used in ComponentHandlers to apply the metadata. When the jsf impls would avoid passing the method bindings, it would be no problem to remove the legacy code, or am I wrong?